# Maven Deploy > Uploaded file name

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I deploy my project (IntelliJ).

[image: file list]

I see that file names contain some numbers. Why is that? Why it is not simple `TryAPI-2.0.jar`?

My pom:

```
    <groupId>de.trymc.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>TryAPI</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>TryAPI</name>

    <!--<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>trymc</id>
            <url>http://132121212u/nexus/content/repositories/trymc</url>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>-->
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>vps348-jycjf-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://121251^515:8040/artifactory/trymc</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <repositories>
        <!-- CloudNet Repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>cloudnet-repo</id>
            <url>http://^25522525.de/repositories/</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Lombok Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HikariCP Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Commons Lang Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spigot / Bukkit  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--- CloudNet-API for Bukkit and BungeeCord -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.dytanic.cloudnet</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudnet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.PXVI</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--- For Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.dytanic.cloudnet</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudnet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.PXVI</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Maven Compiler -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>D:\Development\TryMC.de</outputDirectory>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>de.trymc.api.TryApiPlugin</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

Maven SNAPSHOT artifacts are stored with a time stamp that repositories use to identify which one is the latest of all snapshots.

This is because snapshot artifacts can be overwritten in repositories.

To make a stable version, i.e., `TryAPI-2.0`, you would need to release the artifact, so that it becomes a stable one. Released artifacts can't be overwritten in repositories, and therefore don't need a timestamp. Released artifacts typically go to a separate repository.

Check information about the [Maven release plugin here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html)